# How do I recompile nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger, pcre

I'm setting up a new server (my first!).

I've installed Passenger and used `passenger-install-nginx-module` to install nginx. I've subsequently set it up and it all works.

However my app is Rails 3.1 and therefore uses the asset pipeline, and I didn't realize I needed to have the PCRE library

```
nginx: [emerg] using regex "^/(assets)/" requires PCRE library in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:89
```

It needs it so that the following in `nginx.conf` works properly:

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {  
  root /path/to/public;  
  gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version  
  expires max;  
  add_header  Cache-Control public;  
}
```

I installed PCRE by

`sudo apt-get install libpcre3 libpcre3-dev`

Now that I've added this I believe it is necessary to recompile nginx.

I've seen a few blog posts/ the nginx help about how to recompile it, but I really am a n00b. Can someone point me at step by step instructions?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you get it to work, or still have problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The given answers will not work, because you are trying to use Nginx with Passenger, and Nginx needs the Passenger module also compiled.

Simply running `passenger-install-nginx-module` again will recompile nginx for you. If it doesn't, you can try `rm -r` on /opt/nginx (which is the default location nginx is installed into by Passenger). Be sure to backup your /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf if you value it.

If you are using passenger standalone, and you need to recompile that, remove ~/.passenger/YOUR-MOST-RECENT-INSTALL and simply run passenger start again.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember right, you only need to recompile nginx. Because you compiled your nginx before installed PCRE, nginx can not talk to PCRE.

You can find your configure arguments by writing

```
> nginx -V
```

Copy your arguments: and recompile nginx by doing this

1. Go to your nginx download folder
2. > ./configure [your configure arguments goes here]
3. > make
4. > sudo make install

If it does not work try to add --with-pcre=[path to pcre] to your configure arguments

Hope it will work ;)

Answer (score 0):

There's a [really short how-to on nginx wiki](http://wiki.nginx.org/Install) at the end of the page, the [larger version seems to be available only in russian](http://nginx.org/ru/docs/install.html).